# OpenGl es 2.0 GLSL fragmentColor multiple textures

Tags: android, glsl, multitexturing

I am rendering frame, fragment color is based on two textures, i woudl like to increment value of one of textures in one pass, i mean can i run one program on two framebuffers in one pass?

like gl_fragmentColor1 and gl_fragmentColor2, but gl_fragmentColor2 is bound to second framebuffer, or can i write to texture using sampler2d in some way? Currently i am using color array passed as attribute to shader and calculating color changes on cpu, but approach witch texture is a lot faster, problem is that i cant decrement pixel value when i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES does not allow you to render to multiple textures at once. So no. There may be an extension available, but it would probably only work for NVIDIA hardware.